# In how many ways can $18$ be written as the sum of four distinct positive integers?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

> In how many ways can $18$ be written as the sum of four distinct positive integers? Note: $1 + 3 + 5 + 9$ and $5 + 1 + 3 + 9$ are counted as different ways

---

Other than just bashing it out, how can I do this in a reasonable amount of time where I won't miss anything?

Comment: It would be, but there is the condition of "four **distinct**".

Comment: Oh yeah, so how can I do this in a quick way?

Comment: It seems bashy, but the best way is probably to do casework on the biggest number.

Comment: In case you need (*Mathematica*) code:  `Length[Select[IntegerPartitions[18, {4}], DuplicateFreeQ]]`. For $18$, the answer is $15$ ways.  $$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 12 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
 11 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\
 10 & 5 & 2 & 1 \\
 10 & 4 & 3 & 1 \\
 9 & 6 & 2 & 1 \\
 9 & 5 & 3 & 1 \\
 9 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\
 8 & 7 & 2 & 1 \\
 8 & 6 & 3 & 1 \\
 8 & 5 & 4 & 1 \\
 8 & 5 & 3 & 2 \\
 7 & 6 & 4 & 1 \\
 7 & 6 & 3 & 2 \\
 7 & 5 & 4 & 2 \\
 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$  where numbers must be ordered.

Comment: I can verify that the answer is $360$, I ended up listing the ordered sets of numbers, and then multiplied by 24.

Comment: Hmm, the generating function for writing $n$ as a sum of four distinct positive integers would be $\frac{24 x^{10}}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)}$.  Probably not that helpful as a way to calculate the answer for this particular case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, the best way is casework on the biggest number.

The biggest number must be $12$ or under, because if otherwise it would be impossible.

- Biggest no = 12, there is one quadruple, namely $12, 3, 2, 1$.
- Biggest no = 11, there is one quadruple, namely $11, 4, 2, 1$.
- Biggest no = 10, there are two quadruples, namely $10, 5, 2, 1$ and $10, 4, 3, 1$.
- Biggest no = 9, there are three quadruples, namely $9, 6, 2, 1$ and $9, 5, 3, 1$ and $9, 4, 3, 2$.
- Biggest no = 8, there are four quadruples, namely $8, 7, 2, 1$ and $8, 6, 3, 1$ and $8, 5, 4, 1$ and $8, 5, 3, 2$.
- Biggest no = 7, there are three quadruples, namely $7, 6, 4, 1$ and $7, 6, 3, 2$ and $7, 5, 4, 2$.
- Biggest no = 6, there is one quadruple, namely $6, 5, 4, 3$.

In total there are $1+1+2+3+4+3+1 = 15$ quadruples, each of which can be ordered in $4! = 24$ ways, for a total answer of $$15\cdot 24 = \boxed{360.}$$

Answer (score 1):

The smallest number which can be expressed as the sum of four distinct positive integers is $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10$.  We want to obtain a sum of $18$, so we must add $8$ to this sum.  The number $8$ has $15$ partitions into at most four parts in the positive integers.  They are:
\begin{align*}
8 & = 8\\
  & = 7 + 1\\
  & = 6 + 2\\
  & = 5 + 3\\
  & = 5 + 2 + 1\\
  & = 5 + 1 + 1 + 1\\
  & = 4 + 4\\
  & = 4 + 3 + 1\\
  & = 4 + 2 + 2\\
  & = 4 + 2 + 1 + 1\\
  & = 3 + 3 + 2\\
  & = 3 + 3 + 1 + 1\\
  & = 3 + 2 + 2 + 1\\
  & = 2 + 2 + 2 + 2
\end{align*}
To construct an ordered-quadruple $(a, b, c, d)$ with $a \leq b \leq c \leq d$ which has sum $18$, add partitions of $8$ into at most four parts to $(1, 2, 3, 4)$ by adding the smallest part to $1$, second smallest part to $2$, third smallest part to $3$, and largest part to $4$.  For instance, given the partition $5 + 2 + 1 = 5 + 2 + 1 + 0$ of $8$, we obtain $(1, 2, 3, 4) + (0, 1, 2, 5) = (1, 3, 5, 9)$, which is a strictly increasing quadruple of positive integers with sum $18$.

Hence, there are $15$ strictly increasing quadruples of positive integers with sum $18$.  Since each such quadruple may be permuted in $4!$ ways, the number of ordered quadruples of distinct positive integers with sum $18$ is $15 \cdot 4! = 360$.

Answer (score -1):

> Note: 1+3+5+9 and 5+1+3+9 are counted as different ways

Well, let's just ignore that.  If $a+b+c+d = 18$ there are $4!$ ways to rearrange the terms of $a,b,c,d$ to get $24$ equations $a+b+c+d, a+b+d+c$ etc.

So just count them as though $1+3+5+9$ and $5+1+3+9$ were the same and multiply by $24$.

.....

And stars and bars are the famous way to figure out how many ways to do $a + b + c +d = 16$ where $a < b < c< d$.

Bear with me:  $a + b + c + d = 18$ where $0 < a < b < c < d$ if and only if $(a-1) + (b-2)+(c-3)+(d-4) = 8$ where $0 \le a-1 \le b-2\le c-3 \le d-4$ iff $a' + b'+c'+d' =6$ and $a\le b \le c \le d$.

This is "stars and bars".  Lay out $a' + b' + c' +d' = 8$ "bars" on the table before you.  Then lay out $3$ "stars" between the bars so that you have $a'$ bars, a star, then $b'$ bars, a star, then $c'$ bars, a star, and then $d'$ bars.  That way every sum $a'+b'+c'+d' =8$ is represented by some arrangement of $8$ bars and $3$ stars.

How many ways are there to lay out $8$ bars and $3$ stars.  Well, you have $8+3 =11$ spaces and you can place the three stars anywhere.  The rest of the spaces will be bars.

There are ${11\choose 3} = \frac {9*10*11}{1*2*3} =165$ ways.

So they are $165*24=3960$ ways to make these sums.

....

Note:  Ther are $24$ ways to do $1+3+5+9$ and $5+1+3+9$ and $3+9+1+5$ etc.  $1+3 +5 +9= 18$ coresponds to $0 + 1+2+5=8$ which corresponds precisely to the patter of stars and bars $*|*||*|||||$.

There are $165$ so patterns and so thare are $165$ equations and $24$ ways to arrange the four terms in the equations.